# OperationalErrorFATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

Tags: postgresql, heroku, django-rest-framework, heroku-postgres

I have pushed a Django rest framework API I am working on to heroku, everything was working well and then all of a sudden, I started getting this error whenever I call my endpoints:

*OperationalError at /items/all_items
connection to server at "ec2-3-230-149-158.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (3.230.149.158), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections*

I have increased the `conn_max_age` value as suggested by heroku.

Any idea why I am getting this error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: The issue is number of connections not their age. In fact increasing `conn_max_age` would probably make things worse as it will keep connections around longer then they need to be. Some process is making a lot of connections to the database. You need to find out what that is and deal with from there. Either be more efficient about connecting or increase the allowed connections.

Comment: Alright Adrian, thank you. Will work on that.

Comment: Quick one @Adrian....any idea how I could check which process is making a lot of connections to my db?. I'm using redis yp cache some endpoints, could this be the reason?

Comment: Is Redis caching to the database or in-memory? The best way to see what is making connections is by looking at the Postgres log and/or the [pg_stat_activity view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW). If you are looking at log then it would be helpful to have `log_connections` and `log_disconnections` enable per [What to log](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT)

Comment: Redis is caching to the in-memory. Okay thank you, I will try that out.

Answer (score 0):

It tells you that you have made too many request in a specific amount of time. You should look at how to insert other configurations to your connection pool, like for example:

- max_life_time (Set the maximum lifetime of individual connections. Any connection with a lifetime greater than this will be closed).
- connect_timeout (Set the amount of time to attempt connecting to the database).
- max_connections (Set the maximum number of connections that this pool should maintain.)

Now the specific names in Django may vary but they should be very similar.
Some times max_connections alone is not enough, since your connections may saturate since they are not being closed when not used, and the life_time may help if you know each connection is not supposed to live a certain amount of time, so you are making some cleaning out. There are other configurations like: max_size, min_size, idle_timeout and so forth. You will need to do some research to know what might apply better to your specific scenario.